# how to put a result of mul\add that bigger then dword in a dword register or array (MASM)

Tags: arrays, assembly, size, masm, integer-overflow

Im trying to do `mul` or `add` with two numbers (Masm 32 bit assembly), that the result of it will be bigger then 32 bit.
but the problem is that I don't know how to store the result.

for example, `mul` instruction put the result in `eax` (32 bit register), but if I'm trying to multiply 2 numbers that the result will be bigger then 32 bit, the value is compress in eax, and doesn't have the real result. and the same problem with add..

So, I do a `mul` or `add` two numbers that the result is bigger then 32 bit? I thought of making an array, Make a loop of adding (if I `mul` a number by a 100, so the loop will be 100 times, and inside i'm adding the number to itself), and store the number in the array, so the value will Spreads in all of the array, but 2 problems:

1. when I do: `mov ebx,offset arr` and then `mov [ebx],result`
   the result is not spreads in all of the array, it compress in the first dword cell of the array.. (result - is the result of mul or add, arr  is the array of dword to store the result)
2. I don't know what the length of the array suppose to be, I don't want to put a big number for nothing..

So, I to do mul or add of two numbers that the result of it is bigger then 32 bit, and store this result somewhere, without being compress in 32 bit size?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Read the [documentation for `mul`](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_210.html). The output is in register pair `EDX:EAX`.

As for addition, you only have one bit of overflow at most, which is stored in the carry bit.

You can store 64 bit numbers by taking the high and low words separately, and then computing using both. For example, addition of 64 bit numbers:

```
;assume eax holds low value of one pair and edx holds high value of the same pair
add eax, [low_word_of_other_pair]
adc edx, [high_word_of_other_pair]
;register pair EDX:EAX now holds sum of addition
```

The `adc` instruction adds the other value as well as the carry value.

Comment: Hey, from what I understand from you, the maximum result is 64 bit size. but My program need to present any result, even bigger then 64 bit size. so If the result is bigger then 64 bit and the carry bit is turned on, what am I suppost to do with that information? It's not helping me because I need the exact result of the mul. (Maybe I didn't understand you? can you give an example of how to put in array or register the result of any multiply of 2 numbers , even bigger then 64 bit?) thanks!

Comment: oh wait, the two lines of code you made , is working on any result? even bigger then 64 bit? what I understood is that you mov to 'eax' a part of the result, and do 'edx' the second part of the result + the rest of the result that carry flag hold? can u explain me again because I'm a little confused of what you made up there... thanks again :)

Comment: @RoyKuper - If you want more than 64 bit products, you'll have to implement multiplication yourself. Just do it the way you did in school. As for addition, the `adc` instruction allows you to chain any number of additions, so you can add (or subtract, using `sbb`) as many "parts" as necessary. Simply add more `adc` instructions!